# My keyboard don't work and Num lock and its other lamps are off

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I was working with my keyboard recently and it was fine but my space bar didn't work properly Then I decided to open up the keyboard but without changing anything I close it but when I tried to use it again it didn't work my keyboard is a PS/2 type and its cable is functional when I connect the PS/2 cable all three (numlock capslock scrolllock) lamps turn on but after a moment they would turn off and when I push start button on my computer Num lock lamp would turn on and the two other lamps randomly turn on but when my computer start completely all of them would turn off what should I do to fix my keyboard?

[image: Image of keyboard when it is open]

Comment: Buy a new keyboard or take it to a repair shop.

Comment: PS2 is very particular in how it works. The moment the connection is dropped, it no longer works until you reboot. Your simptoms would suggest a break in the cable or so. Not sure this is easily repairable. Given the history, you are most likely better of replacing the keyboard.